# ErrorDetail(string='Expected a list of items but got type "ReturnDict".', code='not_a_list')

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, factory

When I test `ThankYouMessage` I get error `{'images': {'non_field_errors': [ErrorDetail(string='Expected a list of items but got type "ReturnDict".', code='not_a_list')]}}`

## tests

```
class ThankYouMessagesSerializerTestCase(MediaTestCase, TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.thank_you_message = ThankYouMessageFactory()
        self.thank_you_image = ThankYouImageFactory()

    def test_thank_you_message_deserialize(self) -> None:
        image_data = ThankYouMessageImageSerializer(self.thank_you_image).data
        thank_you_data = ({'text': 'Some text', 'images': image_data})
        serializer = ThankYouMessagesSerializer(data=thank_you_data)
        serializer.is_valid()
        print(serializer.errors)
        # {'images': {'non_field_errors': [ErrorDetail(string='Expected a list of items but got type "ReturnDict".', code='not_a_list')]}}
        self.assertTrue(serializer.is_valid())
```

## models

```
class ThankYouMessage(models.Model):
    donation = models.ForeignKey("donation.Donation", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='thank_message', unique=True)
    text = models.TextField()


class ThankImage(models.Model):
    message = models.ForeignKey("donation.ThankYouMessage", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="thankmessageimages/")
```

## factories

```
class ThankYouMessageFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = ThankYouMessage

    donation = factory.SubFactory(DonationFactory)
    text = factory.Sequence(lambda n: f"Thank you {n}")
When I test При тестировании сериализатора получаю ошибку

class ThankYouImageFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = ThankImage

    image = factory.django.ImageField(name=f"testimage.jpeg", color="blue")
    message = factory.SubFactory(ThankYouMessageFactory)
```

## serializers

```
class ThankYouMessageImageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ThankImage
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ("message", "id")


class ThankYouMessagesSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    images = ThankYouMessageImageSerializer(many=True)
    donation = serializers.CharField(source='donation.id', read_only=True)
    donor_id = serializers.CharField(source='donation.donor.id', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ThankYouMessage
        fields = 'text', 'donation', 'donor_id', 'images'
```

If I write `image_data = ThankYouMessageImageSerializer(self.thank_you_image, many=True).data` I get `TypeError: 'ThankImage' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ThankYouMessage` will have a related field `images` which act as a collection of `ThankYouImage`s, so you'll need your `thank_you_image` as a list. You can build it using `.build_batch()` factory method and serialize it with `many=True` argument.

```py
class ThankYouMessagesSerializerTestCase(MediaTestCase, TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        ...
        self.thank_you_images = ThankYouImageFactory.build_batch(3)

    def test_thank_you_message_deserialize(self) -> None:
        image_data = ThankYouMessageImageSerializer(self.thank_you_images, many=True).data
        ...
```

When I test it, your `image_data` still can't be serialized and showing this error:

> The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.

But I think it's for another topic

---

Btw, why not directly serialize the generated `self.thank_you_message` instead of `thank_you_data`? What are you trying to test here?